# Cooking up a $1$-form satisfying two equalities

Tags: differential-geometry

> Denote the standard coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $x,y$ and let $$X = -y\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + x \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \ \text{ and } Y = x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial}{\partial y}.$$ be vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Find a $1$-form $\omega$ on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ such that $\omega(X)=1$ and $\omega(Y)=0$.

If we let $\omega = adx +bdy$, then computing $\omega(X)$ I concluded that $$\omega(X)= -ay+bx$$ and likewise $$\omega(Y)  =ax+ by.$$

Now I'm looking for $a$ and $y$ such that $$\begin{align*}-ay+bx&= 1 \\ ax+by &= 0. \end{align*}$$

Is there a way for me to cook up such an $a$ and $b$ just from these two equations or do I need to do something clever here? Adding these two I got that $$a(x-y)+b(x+y)=1$$so any $a$ and $b$ satisfying this would also work.

Comment: Start by looking at $\omega_0=x\,dy-y\,dx$. Does this work? How to modify otherwise? To get a deeper understanding of how I came up with this, think of the geometry of these vector fields (change to polar coordinates). Bonus: can $\omega$ be defined on all of $\Bbb{R}^2$? Why or why not? Which is the obstructing condition? You could of course take your two equation and brute-force solve it to get $a(x,y)$ and $b(x,y)$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I know that $X$ corresponds to the kinda anti clockwise rotation and $Y$ would be kinda arrows emanating from the origin? I would like to know also how this brute-forcing would work here just in case.

Comment: Notice that your question is "how do I solve a system of two linear equations in two variables?", which is some 78 orders of magnitude in complexity below even knowing what a differential form is!

Comment: Talking about *brute force* in relation to solving a 2by2 linear system is really, really, reaaaaaaaally an exaggeration.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Sure I didn't notice that this actually reduces to solving a system of linear equations. What do you mean by orders of magnitude below knowing what a differential form is?

Comment: @Ademus simply that solving a linear system of 2 equations with 2 unknowns is something kiddos in middle school can do, while knowing what a differential form even is requires a course in differential geometry (which depending on schools can be 2nd/3rd year of undergrad or even 1st year grad school), so the level of difficulty is completely disproportionate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a system of linear equations in variables $a$ and $b$, where the coefficients happen to be functions of $x$ and $y$, but you can still use any technique to solve the system. For example, with matrices, the system is equivalent to
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
-y & x \\
 x & y
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
a \\ b
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
*Try to work this out yourself before revealing the spoilers:*

> \begin{align} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix} -y & x \\[2pt]  x & y \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \\[2pt] &= -\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} \begin{bmatrix}  y & -x \\ -x & -y \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \\[2pt] &= \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} \begin{bmatrix} -y & x \\ x & y \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \\[2pt] &= \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} \begin{bmatrix} -y \\  x \end{bmatrix}, \end{align}

i.e. the $1$-form is

> $$ \omega = \frac{-y \, dx + x \, dy}{x^2 + y^2} $$.

Notice that it happens that this form is well-defined (and smooth) on the entire plane other than the origin! It didn't have to turn out that way, but it did, so we're done.

It is in some sense dual to the rotation field of constant angular frequency, hence it evaluates on such a field to give the value $1$ and is orthogonal to the radial field, giving value $0$.